# MSACCESS 2002 Linked Table Performance Really Slow

Tags: ms-access

Am trying to import some selective data and create a table in MS Access db  2002 from a linked table. For some odd reason the performance became really bad all of a sudden when importing the data.
I tried googleing and tried various methods like reparing/compacting the db, Changing the SubDataSheet Name to [None] from [Auto] but either one worked.

Can any one please give me some examples to increase the performance of linked tables.
Thank you.

Comment: Are your linked tables from Access also, or are they from an external database?

Comment: @ MATT ..The linked tables are from MS SQL Server.

Comment: What happened just before the performance became bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than selecting information from a linked table and trying to make a local table, when using a database server like MS MSQL, you would be better to create a "Pass Through Query" to do the select work on the server side, and then carry out a simple select * on this pass through to get your data in to a local table. This will give the best results if your first select statement is complex and takes a while for Access to run on a linked table, if that is not the issue then you will need to look at your network speed which connects you to your MS SQL server.